# PHP PayuMoney Integration

Tags: php, payumoney

This is my post request:

```
address1    
address2    
amount => 5000
city    
country     
email => xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
firstname = ankit
furl = http://<SITE_NAME>/respHandler.php
hash = 21673423ca4e2ef5648420c440cf9222f1080dc3c54d19e51286b49459ce0cd29f4f36df6434666f4a2a7951569c57385c7c
e78a93da780ca3210cafb1b3bc61
key =<KEY>
lastname    
pg  
phone=9999999999
productinfo=Event Ticket Booking
service_provider=payu_paisa
state   
surl=http://<SITE_NAME>/respHandler.php
txnid=adc7a7bdfd50478c4fdf
udf1=1
udf2=12
udf3=2
udf4    
udf5    
zipcode
```

When sending this URL: `https://secure.payu.in/_payment`

I get this error:

> "NetworkError: 500 hphp_invoke - https://secure.payu.in/_payment"

The issue is that it is working when the amount is 10 but giving an error when the amount is 5000.

Comment: I guess this data doesn't come 'as is', out of the box. Can't you show some of the code that prepared this, and the way you send it ?

Comment: I think you should ask the provider of the service maybe the error is on their side.

Answer (score 0):

```
$paymentData['key']=MERCHANT_KEY;
$paymentData['txnid']=$txnid;
$paymentData['amount']=$totalAmount;
$paymentData['firstname']=$this->objSess->userName;
$paymentData['email']=$userEmail;
$paymentData['phone']=$this->objSess->userMobile;
$paymentData['productinfo']=json_encode($productInfo);
$paymentData['surl']=SUCCESS_URL;
$paymentData['furl']=FAIL_URL;
$paymentData['service_provider']='payu_paisa';
$paymentData['lastname']='';
$paymentData['curl']='';
$paymentData['address1']='';
$paymentData['address2']='';
$paymentData['city']='';
$paymentData['state']='';
$paymentData['country']='';
$paymentData['zipcode']='';
$paymentData['udf1']='';
$paymentData['udf2']='';
$paymentData['udf3']='';
$paymentData['udf4']='';

$paymentData['udf5']='';

$paymentData['pg']='';

$hashSequence = 'key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5|udf6|udf7|udf8|udf9|udf10';

$hashVarsSeq = explode('|', $hashSequence);
$hash_string = '';  
foreach($hashVarsSeq as $hash_var) {
  $hash_string .= isset($paymentData[$hash_var]) ? $paymentData[$hash_var] : '';
  $hash_string .= '|';
}

$hash_string .= SALT;

$hash = strtolower(hash('sha512', $hash_string));

$code = '
        <script>
            var hash = "'.$hash.'";
            function submitPayuForm() {
              if(hash == "") {
                return;
              }
              var payuForm = document.forms.payuForm;
              payuForm.submit();
            }
        </script>
          <form action="'.PAYU_BASE_URL.'" method="post" name="payuForm"  >
              <input type="hidden" name="key" value="'.MERCHANT_KEY.'" />
              <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="'.$hash.'"/>
              <input type="hidden" name="txnid" value="'.$txnid.'" />
              <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="'.$paymentData['amount'].'" />
              <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="'.$paymentData['firstname'].'" />
              <input type="hidden" name="email" value="'.$paymentData['email'].'" />
              <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="'.$paymentData['phone'].'" />
              <input type="hidden" name="productinfo" value="'. htmlspecialchars($paymentData['productinfo'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'" />
              <input type="hidden" name="surl" value="'.$paymentData['surl'].'" />
              <input type="hidden" name="furl" value="'.$paymentData['furl'].'" />
              <input type="hidden" name="service_provider" value="'.$paymentData['service_provider'].'" />

          </form>
          ';
          echo $code;
          echo "<script>submitPayuForm();</script>";
```

Try this Code

Answer (score 0):

I ma getting the same problem. below 5000 it is working. but if the amount is more that or equal to 5

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) You can search over here if you have related problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
//this is how payumoney payment gateway is  implemented in cakephp3 

$MERCHANT_KEY = "merhcant key"; //merchant key provided by payumoney

$SALT = "salt"; //salt provided by payumoney

$PAYU_BASE_URL = "test.payu.in";

$txnid = '';

if (empty($txnid)) {
    $txnid = substr(hash('sha256', mt_rand() . microtime()), 0, 20);  // Generate random transaction id
}

$hash = '';

$firstname = $sessionUserInfo['first_name']; 

$email = $sessionUserInfo['email'];

$contact_no = $sessionUserInfo['contact_no'];



$hashSequence = ($MERCHANT_KEY . "|" . $txnid . "|" . $totalAmount . "|" . $productInfo . "|" . $firstname . "|" . $email . "|||||||||||" . $SALT);
$hash = strtolower(hash("sha512", $hashSequence));//hash Sequence generation formula

$this->set(compact('PAYU_BASE_URL', 'MERCHANT_KEY', 'SALT', 'PAYU_BASE_URL', 'txnid', 'hash', 'productInfo', 'totalAmount'));//write above code in your controller 

<form action="<?php echo $PAYU_BASE_URL; ?>/_payment" method="post" name="payuForm">

 <?php echo $this->Form->hidden('key', ['name' => 'key', 'value' => $MERCHANT_KEY]); ?>
                                            <?php echo $this->Form->hidden('hash', ['name' => 'hash', 'value' => $hash]); ?>
                                            <?php echo $this->Form->hidden('txnid', ['name' => 'txnid', 'value' => $txnid]); ?>
                                            <?php echo $this->Form->hidden('amount', ['name' => 'amount', 'value' => $totalAmount]); ?>
                                            <?php echo $this->Form->hidden('firstname', ['name' => 'firstname', 'value' => $authUser['first_name']]); ?>
                                            <?php echo $this->Form->hidden('address', ['name' => 'address', 'value' => $authUser['address']]); ?>
                                            <?php echo $this->Form->hidden('email', ['name' => 'email', 'value' => $authUser['email']]); ?>
                                            <?php echo $this->Form->hidden('phone', ['name' => 'phone', 'value' => $authUser['contact_no']]); ?>
                                            <?php echo $this->Form->hidden('productinfo', ['name' => 'productinfo', 'value' => $productInfo]); ?>
                                            <?php echo $this->Form->hidden('surl', ['name' => 'surl', 'value' => SITE_PATH . "Payments/successPayment/"]); ?>
                                            <?php echo $this->Form->hidden('furl', ['name' => 'furl', 'value' => SITE_PATH . "Payments/failUrl/"]); ?>
                                            <?php echo $this->Form->button('Order', array('type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-default btn-md round fa fa-arrow-circle-right ml-5', 'name' => 'submit')); ?>

    </form>//write above code in your ctp file
```

Comment: Please explain your answer,,, Thanks